# Автоматное программирование

Tags: c#, теория-автоматов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем преимущества и недостатки автоматного программирования?

К каким языкам автоматное программирование более применительно? (как с точки зрения парадигмы программирования - функциональное например, так и с точки зрения возможностей языка - возможность метапрограммирования и т.п., особенно интересует C#)

Можно ли автоматное программирование применять для написание логики в играх или для для этого есть более эффективные методы?

Есть ли различие между автоматным программированием и программированием с использованием автоматов или это просто игра слов?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под автоматным программированием? Автоматическая генерация кода и последующая его компиляция или еще что?

Comment: Для микроконтроллера без ОС без этого никуда

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для подробного ознакомления с темой рекомендую посмотреть статьи А.А.Шалыто на соответствующие темы.

Вообще, если немножко броситься в демагогию, то автоматное программирование - это некоторый аналог идеи функционального программирования, но с более конкретной *"практической точки зрения".*

---

Любой логический блок есть конечный автомат *(утрированно, конечно)*, плюсы и минусы тоже вполне очевидны. Так, например, т.к количество состояний такой программы конечно и может изменяться только в определенных ее точках, то становится проще **отладка, поддержка и осознание механизмов работы**.

Из недостатков можно выделить *сложность написания действительно качественного кода*, недостаточность инструментов *IDE* для поддержки такой парадигмы и не слишком большое количество ситуаций, когда автоматное программирование действительно хорошо себя проявляет *"из коробки"* (логические стейт-машины, всякие штуки вроде лексического анализа, может-быть, еще программирование UI).

---

Если интересно, то мое имхо насчет этого такое же как, например, насчет функциональной парадигмы - хорошо в ряде случаев, но не тянет на парадигму. **Т.е намного проще использовать конечный автомат или функциональный стиль программирования для решения конкретной задачи, нежели пытаться решать все задачи в этом стиле.**

P.S *У Шалыто много примеров, есть хорошие, есть натянутые, изучайте :)*